# Is there a way to loop over a json file and get each struct into a separate file -- Golang?

Tags: json, csv, go

So my program is to read through a csv file and convert it into json. i've been able to do that and write the json to a file however i want to be able to take each struct or object from this json file and write to a file.

i've attached my code for more understanding

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/csv"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

type NftRecord struct{
    SeriesNumber     int    `json:"Series Number"`
    Name             string `json:"Name"`
  //TheDescriptor    string `json:"The Descriptor"`
  //NewName          string `json:"New Name"`
    Hash             string `json:"Hash"`
    UUIDs            string `json:"UUIDs"`
    Description      string `json:"Description"`
    DriveLink        string `json:"Drive Link"`
}

func createRecordsList(data [][]string) []NftRecord{
    var recordList []NftRecord
    for i, line := range data{
        if i > 0{
            var rec NftRecord
            for j, field := range line{
                if j == 0{
                    var err error
                    rec.SeriesNumber, err = strconv.Atoi(field)
                    if err != nil{
                        continue
                    }
                }else if j == 4{
                    rec.Name = field
                }else if j == 7 {
                    rec.Description = field
                }else if j ==6{
                    rec.UUIDs = field
                }else if j == 5{
                    rec.Hash = field
                }else if j == 8{
                    rec.DriveLink = field
                } else if j == 13{
                    var err error 
                    if err != nil{
                        continue
                    }
                }
            }
            recordList = append(recordList, rec)
        }
    }
    return recordList
}

func main(){
    f, err := os.Open("./scaler.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer f.Close()

    csvReader := csv.NewReader(f)
    data, err := csvReader.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    recordList := createRecordsList(data)

    jsonData, err := json.MarshalIndent(recordList, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    _ = ioutil.WriteFile("./test.json", jsonData, 0644)

    fmt.Println(string(jsonData))

    //hashing
    hash := sha256.New()
    if _, err := io.Copy(hash, f); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    sum := fmt.Sprintf("%x", hash.Sum(nil))
    fmt.Println(sum)
}
```

i've tried pretty much everything i guess, i'm hoping i could get past this as i've got other features to add.

This is the JSON below

```json
{
  "Series Number": 301,
  "Name": "wendy-the -banker",
  "Hash": "D615D6E161E5F820A2B9F5C3ED3867BE0AA9F16DDCA00A0550E30E29A0B467AD",
  "UUIDs": "587645e2-5ace-11ed-9b6a-0242ac120002",
  "Description": "Wendy loves working in the bank, as she gets to meet different people.",
  "Drive Link": "Link"
},
{
  "Series Number": 302,
  "Name": "uduak-the -dark horse",
  "Hash": "5A63A94F455D367EC0AA39F57F827DDBECD3F335C817ED5A76460A2AB8E9068A",
  "UUIDs": "58764862-5ace-11ed-9b6a-0242ac120002",
  "Description": "Uduak looks innocent and has the whole apartment bugged",
  "Drive Link": "Link"
},
```

Comment: What does your JSON file look like? Sample data would be useful.

Comment: Do you mean a separate (JSON?) file for each NftRecord in the slice you get back from createRecordsList?

Comment: @NicholasCarey i've added some JSON for understanding

Comment: @Ephraim-the-program — that's not syntactically valid JSON.

Comment: @NicholasCarey please how do you mean ? i'm kinda lost here

Comment: Is your JSON document (1) a list/array of object, or (2) an object with other objects as its properties?

Answer (score 1):

Loop over recordList. For each element marshall it to JSON and write it to a unique file. You’ll have to have a unique file naming scheme but a trivial one to implement would be a counter (eg 1.json, 2.json, etc).